# adding elements to empty json array and removing them

Tags: json, arrays

I have created an empty json object having an array itemlist(which further contains itemid and title of an item) by this:

```
var jsonObj = {};
jsonObj.itemlist=[];
jsonObj.itemlist.push({});
```

Firstly, have i done the declaration correctly?

Secondly, the title and itemid are generated dynamically so i need to add them to the itemlist array. I tried this but it keeps only one array element:

```
jsonObj.itemlist['title']=gentitle;
jsonObj.itemlist['itemid']=genitemid;
```

How can i add multiple elements (not all at once) if i have an empty array of itemlists?

Also, i also need to remove a particular array element based on the title of the element. How can that be done? I think the splice and delete function can be used for this, but how can i find the index of that element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

since you already pushed a empty object into the array, you need to modify that object:

```
jsonObj.itemlist[0]['title']=gentitle;
jsonObj.itemlist[0]['itemid']=genitemid;
```

To add more objects, you can do the same thing: push in an empty object, then modify that object. Or, you can create an object, modify it, then push it into the list.

```
var new_obj = {'title':gentitle, 'itemid':genitemid};
jsonObj.itemlist.push( new_obj );
```

To delete objects with certain attribute value:

```
for (var i = jsonObj.itemlist.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
    if(jsonObj.itemlist[i]['title'] == "to-be-removed")
        jsonObj.itemlist.splice(i,1);
```

Note that you need to go backward, otherwise the `splice` will mess up the array indexes

Comment: The array is supposed to have more elements in it. And the addition of elements is supposed to be automatic, as in a online shopping cart. Adding just one element won't solve my purpose. What should i do if multiple elements are to be added.

Comment: The pushing works... Thanks! :) Can you also tell me how to remove array element by matching the title of array elements with that of the to-be-removed element?

Comment: @VatsalJuneja updated again.. should be enough for this question

Comment: Was more than enough.. The delete was easy enough, guess i was just not confident enough to think... Thanks.. :)